# Hiding Url After Links Clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm running a Movie / TV Shows Streaming website and the past few days I've got people from other similar website coming to my site and taking my links so is it possible to hide the links in the address bar so it would be harder for him to get my links and is it possible to hide on right click as well.

Here is my link code.

```
<span class="movie_version_link"
{if $val.link}
{if $val.type == 'PutLocker' || $val.type == 'SockShare' || $val.type == 'PromptFile'}
<img src="/templates/svarog/images/stars.gif" title="Fast Streaming"> 
{/if} 
<a href="{$val.link}" onclick="return addHit('0', '1')" rel="nofollow" title="Watch {$mov.title} on {$val.type}" style="font-size:15px;" target="_blank">Version {counter}</a>      {/if}
</span>
```

Could someone please help.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Well it most be possible because primewire.ag is running they're links though a external.php file and and replaces the domain name with they'es.

Comment: You can make a redirection page - asking how to is probably too broad a scope for SO - but you cannot hide the address bar location. If it was, then every www.bankofamericasecurelogin.com website would be much more successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't simple method to hide this url, but you can take an advantage of the situation:

Instead of inserting plain links create redirect urls. Store your links in database with `id` key and create a file, for example

`http://yoursite.com/redirect.php?id={stored_link_id}`

and check referer value when redirecting - if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` would be from your site then redirect to correct url by using 301 redirection:

`header('Location: ' . $targetUrl);`

if link comes from another site display an advertisment or redirect to your page.

Comment: This method will also allow you to record data about which links on your site are being clicked on and which are not.  Great post.